# Raw output file got damaged

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-processing, intel-oneapi, onevpl

I’m working on oneVPL samples from this GitHub repository (https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneAPI-samples ) and I’m trying to build hello-vpp sample. After running the program with the command in readme.md file, I wanted to increase the video size to 1280x720. While playing the raw output file, I used the below command

```
fplay -video_size 1280x720 rawvideo out.raw
```

My raw output file got damaged. A buffered video got played. How do I change the width and height of the output file? Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below command:

```
ffplay -video_size 1280x720 -pixel_format bgra -f rawvideo out.raw
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter. Example assuming `video.raw` is 640x360:

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 640x360 -pixel_format rgba -vf scale=1280:720 video.raw
```